# How to split comma separated string and get n values in Spark Scala dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How to take only 2 data from `arraytype` column in Spark Scala?
I got the data like `val df = spark.sqlContext.sql("select col1, col2 from test_tbl")`.

I have data like following:

```
col1  | col2                              
---   | ---
a     | [test1,test2,test3,test4,.....]   
b     | [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,.....]
```

I want to get data like following:

```
col1| col2
----|----
a   | test1,test2
b   | a1,a2
```

When I am doing `df.withColumn("test", col("col2").take(5))` it is not working. It give this error:

> value take is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName

How can I get the data in above order?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? What does happen?

Comment: it gives error: value take is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `withColumn` you can call udf `getPartialstring`  for that you can use `slice` or `take` method like below **example** snippet untested.

```
  import sqlContext.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val getPartialstring = udf((array : Seq[String], fromIndex : Int, toIndex : Int) 
   => array.slice(fromIndex ,toIndex ).mkString(","))
```

your caller will appear like

```
 df.withColumn("test",getPartialstring(col("col2"))
```

`col("col2").take(5)` is failing because [column](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala) doesn't have a method `take(..)`  that's why  your error message says

> error: value take is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName

You can use udf approach to tackle this.

Comment: this also works I am not able to accept the answer. I think still I am novice :), please forgive me for this

Answer (score 2):

You can use the array Column's `apply` function to get each individual item up to a certain index, and then build a new array using the `array` function:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// Sample data:
val df = Seq(
  ("a", Array("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6")),
  ("a", Array("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5")),
  ("c", Array("c1", "c2"))
).toDF("col1", "col2")

val n = 4
val result = df.withColumn("col2", array((0 until n).map($"col2"(_)): _*))

result.show(false)
// +----+--------------------+
// |col1|col2                |
// +----+--------------------+
// |a   |[a1, a2, a3, a4]    |
// |a   |[b1, b2, b3, b4]    |
// |c   |[c1, c2, null, null]|
// +----+--------------------+
```

Note that this will "pad" results with `null`s for records with arrays smaller than `n`.

Comment: thanks it is working fine, I am not able to give you point and accept right now i will do it later